# Missing Constructor for Initialization

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

Hi I am trying to debug a program and one of the errors I am receiving is 'Missing Initialization for Constructor'. Do I need to declare the vector upfront and how do I initialize it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    double get_x() { return x; }
    double get_y() { return y; }
    bool set_x(double arg) {
        x = arg;
        return true;
    }
    bool set_y(double arg) {
        y = arg;
        return true;
    }
    Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Point(double argx, double argy) : x(argx), y(argy) {
    }
};


class Vector {
private:
    Point A;
    Point B;
public:
    Point get_A() { return A; }
    Point get_B() { return B; }
    Vector(const Point &arg1, const Point &arg2) : A(arg1), B(arg2)
    {
        //this->A = arg1;
        //this->B = arg2;
        //A = arg1;
        //B = arg2;
    }
    void set_A(const Point &arg) {
        A = arg;
    }
    void set_B(const Point &arg) {
        B = arg;
    }
    static Vector add_vector(const Vector &vector1, const Vector &vector2) {
        if (&vector1.B != &vector2.A) {

            //Error 1 Vector V1 No Matching constructor for initialization for 'vector'

            Vector rval;
            return rval;
        }

        Point one = vector1.A;
        Point two = vector2.B;

        Vector newvector(one, two);
        //newvector.A = one;
        //newvector.B = two;
        return newvector;

    }
    Vector add_vector(const Vector &arg) {
        // Type of this?  Vector *; These three lines are equivalent:
        //Point one = this->A;
        //Point one = (*this).A;
        Point one = A;

        Point two = arg.B;

        Vector newvector(one, two);
        //newvector.A = one;
        //newvector.B = two;
        return newvector;
    }

};


int main() {

    //Error 2 Vector v No Matching constructor for initialization for 'vector'


   Vector v;
    cout << "(" << v.get_A().get_x() << ", " << v.get_A().get_y() << "),\n" <<
    "(" << v.get_B().get_x() << ", " << v.get_B().get_y() << ")\n";

    //Error 3    Vector V1 No Matching constructor for initialization for 'vector'


    Vector v1(1,2), v2(2,3);
    Vector res = Vector::add_vector(v1, v2);
    cout << "(" << res.get_A().get_x() << ", " << res.get_A().get_y() << "),\n" << 
    "(" << res.get_B().get_x() << ", " << res.get_B().get_y() << ")\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is your class is not default constructable.

```
Vector rval;
```

Requires a default constructor.  Since you provided a user defined constructor the compiler will no longer make a default constructor for you.

To create a default constructor for `Vector` you can use

```
Vector() = default;
```

If you have C++11 or higher or you can use

```
Vector() {}
```

For pre C++11.

I am not sure what you are trying to do with

```
Vector v1(1,2)
```

`Vector` needs two `Point`s and each `Point` needs 2 values.

Comment: Thanks, in regards to Vector v1(1,2) this program I have to debug for an assignment. So part of it is asking do I need this and what does it do or what is it intended to do. Thanks @NathanOliver

Comment: @Bigboy6 I am not sure.  `Vector` takes `Point`s and `1` is not a `Point`.  Without knowing what whoever wrote the code intended to do I could only guess.